# Using dependency injection while constructing class objects that may contain lists of other class objects

Tags: c#

I am trying to reduce coupling in my application by using dependency injection in class constructors when I can. I am having a problem wrapping my head on how to do this with classes that contain lists of other complex class objects that may not be defined at the construction of a new object.

Here's an example:
I have a Person class. This person class has lists of class objects as properties(Clothes, Weapons, Pets, Vehicles). The person class may not have clothes, weapons, pets, or vehicles at construction, but may acquire them later. If I create methods within the person class that construct new Clothes, Weapons, Pets, or Vehicles, that will tightly couple my Person class to the other classes. Even if I use factories to construct these objects, calling the factory method that constructs the class objects in a Person method will still couple my Person class to the other classes.

I have tinkered around with interfaces and factories but it seems that if a Person method causes the construction of a Clothes, Weapons, Pets, or Vehicles class object, the Person is now coupled to that class.

I have a few questions regarding this kind of scenario.

1. Is it bad design to have a class contain lists of other complex class objects for the convenience of maintaining their relationship to each other?
2. Is there any way to maintain the relationship between these items while keeping coupling loose?
3. Am I putting too much emphasis on coupling in this scenario? Is is actually important to de-couple these classes in this case or am I overthinking this?

Comment: If they are optional, declare them nullable. Another alternative is property injection and have them built outside of the Person Class. That way, they do not depend on anything other than the built objects. It would be the responsibility of another class to construct and pass those dependencies to the Person, i.e a GameManager class or similar. SOLID principles should help you to some extent on figuring out coupling and where responsibilities should be.

Comment: first, i want to say that this is better of in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

second, if you want to create objects decoupled, you will have to use interfaces, and/or let all of the things (Person, Pet, etc..) be part of a model which gets the instances for you

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the code for review as it belongs to a sensitive project (I would get fired). That's why I posed this example scenario that closely mimics the situation I have. The default constructor does initialize these properties as null. It's when I create a method in the "Person" that kicks off the construction of Weapons and sets the Weapons List is when the coupling occurs. So If I had a service (A Person Manager) construct  the weapons list (I tried this with a factory), would the Person class not be coupled to the service class (Person Manager)?